# I need to stop a DIV disappearing when I mouse over the link in the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html

Here is my complete code. When I mouse over on popupcontact div it show the divtoshow div over it, and it has one link of name rahul, and when I mouse over the link, it hide the div name divtoshow.

My div should hide when I mouseout not when I mouseover the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="popupContact"  style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;width:100px;height:50px;background-color:orange;border:1px solid red ;">
    </div>
    <div id="divtoshow" style="display:none;background-color:green; border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;">
    dsfdssd <div><a href="#">rahul</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popup_pos=$('#popupContact').offset();
    var timer;
     $("#popupContact").mouseover(function() {
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null
           }
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($("#VersionSelectField").is(':hidden'));
            if(!$("#VersionSelectField").is(':hidden')){
                $("#divtoshow").css('position',"absolute"); 
                $("#divtoshow").css('top',popup_pos.top-20);    
                $("#divtoshow").css('left',popup_pos.left-20);  
                $("#divtoshow").fadeIn(300);
                 $("#popupContact").hide();
            }

        }, 100);

        });

     $("#divtoshow").mouseout(function() {
            if(timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null
               }
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $("#divtoshow").fadeOut("slow");
                 $("#popupContact").show();

            }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) like this:

```
$("#divtoshow").mouseout(function() {
```

Use [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), like this:

```
$("#divtoshow").mouseleave(function() {
```

This *won't* fire when entering a child element like `mouseout` will, which is currently hiding when you don't want it to.

---

One other code tip, you can at least chain on the `#divtoshow` selector, or even better chain and pass an object to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$("#divtoshow").css({ position: "absolute", 
                      top: popup_pos.top-20, 
                      left: popup_pos.left-20 })
               .fadeIn(300);
```

Also, it's not an issue for your markup, but if `#popupContact` had a child element you'd have similar issues with [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), that not-firing-on-children equivalent is [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).

Comment: @Rahul - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers if they resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

when using setTimeout and clearTimeout, always make sure to use the full path to these functions by calling window.setTimeout and window.clearTimeout.

I have found that sometimes it won't work properly in some versions of IE if you don't.